# GUI help for large data sets

Tags: user-interface

I am new to this forum and would like your help to build a new GUI. The requirement is to build a GUI that will require reading data from large files (files could go upto 10 GB). Not just plain reading but also processing certain amount of data form these files. It will be one by one reading of line(on button click),processing and then displaying it on the GUI. Which technology would be best. Any help will be appreciated. GUI will contain tables as well as graphs. Thanks

Comment: question is too broad. what have you tried and specific issues have you have? how to write a good question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask